# Unit Testing C++ static library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I've made a small C++ library and I'd like to test it. However, due to the nature of static libraries, I can't run   a main()  function on them... though that's exactly what I'd like to do. I want to create a simple header and source files that make use of the library's classes, so I can debug it if anything doesn't go well. I could create a different project but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to go. 
Is there any other way I could do that?  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 as the IDE.

Comment: _" I could create a different project  ..."_ So you are working with some particular IDE? For most of them having a separate unit testing project is the right way to go.

Comment: Oh,  my bad! I use VS2015 and I edited my question with it. I thought a new project was "overkill" , but I'm going to look into that now

Comment: VS has a built-in testing project template and test system built-in (MSTest). Look at VS' documentation.

Comment: @Dai Can't upvote your comment (out of votes today), but I was about writing merely the same.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to look into that too, looks promising.

Comment: Just test your library the same way a user would use your library.

Comment: also could also consider google test (very easy) and boost::test (slightly harder to set up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, due to the nature of static libraries, I can't run a main() function on them... though that's exactly what I'd like to do.

For unit testing, it ends up that you'll need to have a `main()` function that triggers running the tests (that's what's called a *test runner*).

You're right, that you can't provide a `main()` function with your library, since this would lead to clashes with other programs that link to your library.

So, for most build systems (or IDEs) that's built as a separate target (project), that involves to build the executable test runner target.

VS2015 has a [builtin project template](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/create-and-run-unit-tests-vs) to provide this functionality.

Other build systems might rely to unit-testing frameworks like [gtest](https://github.com/google/googletest) that also provides a `main()` to realize the test runner on demand.

Comment: The link is broken for the builtin project template.